# Is it possible to avoid a page (or column) break in a list between item and sub-item?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Assume I have an unordered list with sub-items (i.e.: pressing an extra TAB within the same list).

[image: Screenshot showing undesired page break between list item and sub-item]

Is it possible to avoid a page or column break between a list item and the first sub-item (assuming the item just needs a single line) automatically (as you could do between heading and the paragraph following)?

I'd like to have the (first line of the) first sub-item on the same page as the parent item (at least if that fits on a single line), but I see it's a recursive problem (consider your page only holds 6 lines, and you have a nested list eight levels deep with every item just needing a single line).

I'm using

```
Version: 7.5.7.1 (x86) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 47eb0cf7efbacdee9b19ae25d6752381ede23126
CPU threads: 8; OS: Windows 10.0 Build 19044; UI render: Skia/Raster; VCL: win
Locale: de-DE (de_DE); UI: de-DE
Calc: CL threaded
```